# ORA-02070: database [MySQL] does not support subqueries in this context. - ORACLE

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have the following tables:

MySQL table: **member_interact**

```
CREATE TABLE `member_interact` (
  `INT_MEMBER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `INT_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `INT_SOURCE` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `INT_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `INT_TYPE` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `COPY_TO_STG` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NO',
  `NEW_STG_SEQ` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COPY_TO_STG_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`INT_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `INT_ID_UNIQUE` (`INT_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31246 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

Oracle table: **MEMBER_INTERACT_MYSQL_STG**

```
  CREATE TABLE "JTI_HTP"."MEMBER_INTERACT_MYSQL_STG" 
   (    "INT_MEMBER_ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "INT_ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "INT_SOURCE" NVARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "INT_DATE" DATE, 
    "INT_TYPE" NVARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "INSERTING_DATE" DATE, 
    "MYSQL_ID" NUMBER(12,0)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
```

Basically, I need to copy *member_interact* into *member_interact_mysql_stg* with adding new columns as follow:

1. MEMBER_INTERACT_MYSQL_STG.STG_INT_ID = NEW_SEQ
2. MEMBER_INTERACT_MYSQL_STG.MYSQL_INT_ID = MEMBER_INTERACT.INT_ID
3. MEMBER_INTERACT.COPY_TO_STG = 'YES', once the copy operation is completed.
4. MEMBER_INTERACT.NEW_STG_SEQ = MEMBER_INTERACT_MYSQL_STG.STG_INT_ID

I have created the following Procedures:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE COPY_MYSQL_MOB_INT_TO_STG(
    P_BATCH_NO IN NUMBER)
IS
  CURSOR src
  IS
    SELECT *
    FROM "jtipartn_mydb"."MEMBER_INTERACT"@"JTIPARTNER_HTP"
    WHERE "NEW_STG_SEQ" IS NULL
    AND "INT_ID" <= 7000;

    STG_INT_ID NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR des IN src
  LOOP
    STG_INT_ID := STG_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
    INSERT
    INTO MEMBER_INTERACT_MYSQL_STG VALUES
      (
        DES.INT_MEMBER_ID,
        STG_INT_ID,
        des.int_source,
        des.int_date,
        des.int_type,
        NULL,
        DES.INT_ID
      );
      UPDATE_COPIED_MEMBER_INTERACT(STG_INT_ID, DES.INT_ID);
           COMMIT;
  END LOOP;

END;
```

---

```
create or replace PROCEDURE UPDATE_COPIED_MEMBER_INTERACT( STG_INT_ID IN NUMBER, MYSQL_INT_ID IN NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
    UPDATE "jtipartn_mydb"."MEMBER_INTERACT"@"JTIPARTNER_HTP"
    SET "COPY_TO_STG"     = 'YES',
        "NEW_STG_SEQ"       = STG_INT_ID
    WHERE "INT_ID" = MYSQL_INT_ID;
END;
```

In fact, there were one procedure to update both tables, but due the error I received I find it might be easier to eliminate the eror by separating the procedure into two. 
The error I get is :

ORA-02047: cannot join the distributed transaction in progress
ORA-06512: at "JTI_HTP.UPDATE_COPIED_MEMBER_INTERACT", line 19
ORA-06512: at "JTI_HTP.COPY_MYSQL_MOB_INT_TO_STG", line 28
ORA-06512: at line 6

line 19 is where the second procedure is called. Which I suspected that something has to do with the MySQL table update.

**UPDATE**

I have updated my script based on @Maheswaran Ravisankar answer as follow:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COPY_MYSQL_MOB_INT_TO_STG_V3(
    P_BATCH_NO IN NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MEMBER_INTERACT_MYSQL_STG
    SELECT "INT_MEMBER_ID",
      STG_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
      "INT_SOURCE",
      "INT_DATE",
      "INT_TYPE",
      CURRENT_DATE,
      "INT_ID"
    FROM "jtipartn_mydb"."MEMBER_INTERACT"@"JTIPARTNER_HTP" des
    WHERE "NEW_STG_SEQ" IS NULL; 

    UPDATE "jtipartn_mydb"."MEMBER_INTERACT"@"JTIPARTNER_HTP" A
    SET "COPY_TO_STG" = 'YES',
      "NEW_STG_SEQ"   =
      (SELECT STG_INT_ID 
      FROM MEMBER_INTERACT_MYSQL_STG B 
       WHERE A."INT_ID" = B.STG_INT_ID
      );
END;
```

However, I am getting error *ORA-02070: database JTIPARTNER_HTP does not support subqueries in this context*.

Comment: Perhaps, you have a cursor already opened on tht table, and you try to update the same, before closing it?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar I placed *OPEN src;* inside the loop and *CLOSE src;* before calling update procedure. I am getting: ORA-06511: PL/SQL: cursor already open

Comment: No, you are using an implicit cursor here. the open and close oracle do it for you.(as part of for loop) You might need to change your logic here. By doing the inserts separately. and after the loop, update the table, by saving the generated sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    INSERT
    INTO MEMBER_INTERACT_MYSQL_STG
      SELECt
        DES.INT_MEMBER_ID,
        STG_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
        des.int_source,
        des.int_date,
        des.int_type,
        NULL,
        DES.INT_ID
     FROM "jtipartn_mydb"."MEMBER_INTERACT"@"JTIPARTNER_HTP" des
     WHERE "NEW_STG_SEQ" IS NULL
  /*  RETURNING STG_INT_ID BULK COLLECT INTO SOME RECORD; --Needed if only processed in array!*/
```

And update like below,

```
UPDATE "jtipartn_mydb"."MEMBER_INTERACT"@"JTIPARTNER_HTP" A
SET "COPY_TO_STG"     = 'YES',
    "NEW_STG_SEQ"     = (SELECT STG_INT_ID FROM MEMBER_INTERACT_MYSQL_STG B
                         WHERE A.INT_ID = B.INT_ID);
```

(OR)

```
FOR REC IN (SELECT  STG_INT_ID,INT_ID FROM MEMBER_INTERACT_MYSQL_STG)
LOOP
    UPDATE "jtipartn_mydb"."MEMBER_INTERACT"@"JTIPARTNER_HTP" A
    SET "COPY_TO_STG"     = 'YES',
        "NEW_STG_SEQ"     = REC.STG_INT_ID
    WHERE A.INT_ID = REC.INT_ID;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Your logic is much great. I updated my script accordingly. However, I am getting error with regards to using RETURNING line that is not properly ended. Is the way I used RETURNING with insert correct?

Comment: oh, Now you have to forget the `CURSOR` and the `LOOP`. As we use the `SELECT` for `INSERT` itself, so a cursor is not required. Also, your can ignore the `RETURNING` part.

Comment: Thanks, I updated accordingly. Howevere, I am unable to update MySQL table via subquery statement. I get the error *ORA-02070: database JTIPARTNER_HTP does not support subqueries in this context*

Comment: Wow, I expected, So, let's process record by record now!